# Trigonometric deducing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $\tan {x\over2} =\frac{ 1 - \cos(x)} {\sin(x)}$, deduce that $\tan {\pi\over12} = 2-\sqrt3$.

I know $\tan {x\over2} =\frac{ 1 - \cos(x)} {\sin(x)}$ is true and I can prove it by squaring and taking a square root of the right side then I multiply by $0.5\over0.5$. And I will use 
$$\cos{x\over2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}$$ and
$$\sin{x\over2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$$

But I do not understand the part of deducing.

Comment: The question does not make sense. Where did you get it?

Comment: I am helping someone with an assignment. I am real not getting the deducing part and of course as tan(x/12)= 2- (3)^0.5 is false on my level of understanding.

Comment: For the $\tan(x/12)$ you definitely need an expression in terms of $x$, so there I suspect there is something missing.

Comment: It should be $\tan(\frac{\pi}{12})=2-\sqrt{3}$.
It is very easy since $\tan(\frac{\pi}{12})=\frac{1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})}=\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}{\frac12}=2-\sqrt{3}$

Comment: I guess the person you're helping copied out $x$ instead of $π.$ Sometimes they may look almost the same, especially if the writer is in a hurry, and the pupil doesn't care about what they're copying anyway.

Comment: I real hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is what you need to solve:

Show that $\tan(\frac{1}{12}\pi)=2-\sqrt{3}$, given that 
$$\tan(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}.$$

This can be shown quite easily as $\cos(\frac{1}{6}\pi)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{6}\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$. (These are well known values and I suspect you do not need to proof this.)

Comment: tan(pi/12) not 1/12